# Got more than 200 reputation in a day?

Tags: support, reputation

Not that I'm complaining, but now I've got more than 200 reputation two days in a row. Just from a few edits, questions, and lots of upvotes on answers, no bounties. The site is Academia, out of beta (if that makes a difference). What are the *real* rules here?

This question is deemed duplicate, but the linked question states 200 reputation is a hard limit, and that bounties are counted separately. So yes, you can get more than 200 a day *by adding bounties*. This is ***emphatically*** not my case. What gives?

Comment: Rep from acceptances isn't capped.

Comment: Specifically, the linked question says bounties *and* accepts are counted separately.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've *no* bounties

Comment: @vonbrand: Which is why I emphasized that accepts are *also* counted separately. As far as I can tell, that explains all the extras.

Comment: From the linked question: "Bounties *and* the bonuses for accepted answers..."

Comment: Looks like you fail to understand the meaning of the term "accepted answer". This means the user who wrote the question that you have answered clicked a special button, and by this doing something called "accepting an answer", and chose your answer. Among other things, this gives the author of that answer (this means the user who wrote the answer) 15 reputation points, which are NOT part of upvotes, and are not bound to the daily reputation limit. For example yesterday you had two of your answers accepted (e.g. [this one](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/63317/13859)), so you reached 230.

Comment: If you still don't understand and think you are beyond the rules, I fear we can't explain the rules to you, and you'll just have to accept that's how things work in Stack Exchange.